# Simple logging in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm just trying to design a simple logging system based on two functions like the following:

```
-- Prints before (if logging is on), does action, 
-- prints after (if logging is on), returns action
log :: b -> c -> IO a -> IO a
log before after action = ...

-- Sets logging on/off for the duration of the passed action.
setLog :: Bool -> IO a -> IO a
setLog doLog action = ...
```

i.e.

```
setLog False $
  log "This doesn't get printed" "Neither does this" (putStr "But this does")
```

Would just print:

```
"But this does"
```

But this:

```
setLog True $
  log "This does get printed" "This does too" (putStr "And this does")
```

Would print:

```
"This does get printed"
"And this does"
"This does too"
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to set up.
Alternatively, if there's a better way to approach this I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the duration of the passed action"? For example, `return (sum [1..10^7])` returns immediately but then will take some time to evaluate once its value is demanded. You can use `Control.Exception.evaluate` or the like to evaluate it to some normal form. What is the goal of having a dynamic switch to toggle logging? Why not have your code live inside `WriterT IO a` so you can decide what to do with your logs later?

Comment: @user2407038: See the edits.

Comment: If you only want to use `setLog` immediately followed by `log` then just have one function: `log :: Bool -> String -> String -> IO a -> IO a; log b x y ac = if b then putStrLn x >> ac >>= \a -> putStrLn y >> return a else ac`

Comment: @user2407038: That many not be the case. Users of setlog should need to know whether the IO action they're running actually has calls to log or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. The function I wrote would satisfy both of the examples.

Comment: When using `setLog b x`, `x` could be a complex sequence of IO actions with multiple log statements. `setLog` should turn them all on or off.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're asking? Are you asking if there's a better design? Or are you asking for the code that implements the design you proposed?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this pretty easily with the `StateT` monad transformer.  As a short example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

data LogState = LogOff | LogOn
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Show, Read)

newtype LogT m a = LogT { unLogT :: StateT LogState m a}
    deriving (Functor, Monad, Applicative, MonadState LogState, MonadTrans, MonadIO)

runLog :: Monad m => LogT m a -> m a
runLog action = evalStateT (unLogT action) LogOn


loggingEnabled :: (Functor m, Monad m) => LogT m Bool
loggingEnabled = fmap (== LogOn) get

log' :: (Functor m, Monad m) => (l -> LogT m ()) -> l -> l -> m a -> LogT m a
log' logger before after action = do
    doLog <- loggingEnabled
    when doLog $ logger before
    result <- lift action
    when doLog $ logger after
    return result

-- The function `log` already exists in Prelude as the logarithm, use a different name
log_ :: (Functor m, MonadIO m) => String -> String -> m a -> LogT m a
log_ = log' (liftIO . putStrLn)

enableLogging :: Monad m => LogT m ()
enableLogging = put LogOn

disableLogging :: Monad m => LogT m ()
disableLogging = put LogOff


main :: IO ()
main = runLog $ do
    enableLogging
    log_ "You'll see this" "Then this" $
        putStrLn "First action"
    disableLogging
    log_ "But not this" "or this" $
        putStrLn "Second action"
```

Thanks to `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, we can automatically generate the useful instances for our new monad transformer, such as `Functor`, `Monad`, `MonadIO`, and `MonadTrans`.  We can use it just like it's a `StateT LogState` monad, and use this to store whether or not logging is enabled.  You'd be able to extend this pretty simply if you wanted, say if you wanted to control logging level (DEBUG/INFO/WARNING/ERROR), just change `LogState` to fit your needs.  I've also left `log'` in there as a generic logger, in case you would rather have it write to a `WriterT` monad, or maybe write to a file, or do something else entirely.  It's pretty flexible.

Comment: Why not doing this with an `ReaderT` instead?

Comment: @chaosmasttter `ReaderT` is for when you have a static configuration.  This allows you to dynamically turn logging on and off, even potentially based on user input or computed values.  It may not be that useful, but it seemed to be more how OP wanted it.  The big difference would just be to switch from `get` to `ask` and get rid of the commands that use `put`.  `StateT` is replaced by `ReaderT` and `MonadState` is replaced by `MonadReader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setLog :: Bool -> ((String -> IO ()) -> IO a) -> IO a 
setLog True = ($ putStrLn)
setLog False = ($ (const $ return ()))

log' f x y ac = f x >> ac >>= \a -> f y >> return a 

test0 = setLog False $ \f -> do
          log' f "This doesn't get printed" "Neither does this" (putStr "But this does")

test1 = setLog True $ \f -> do
          log' f "This does get printed" "This does too" (putStr "And this does")
```